# axios doesn't work in my original project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

axios doesn't work in my original project, but when I try from a different place it works fine

My real project error

[image]

The project I tested on codesandbox, the codes are exactly the same

[image]

Comment: Maybe some firewalls or so on your local machine?

Comment: Please try to use 'fetch' instead of axios. Thank you

Comment: I created a new project on the local machine and I was able to pull the data with axios without any problems.